# Can water be included in an ICE table if it is not the solvent and is a product?

Tags: equilibrium, water, concentration

The question that I have is whether you will count water in a Fischer esterification equilibrium problem where the equation is

carboxylic acid + ethanol --> ethyl acetate + Water

We need to find the concentrations of the different components at equilibrium and are also given the equilibrium constant. I know that if water is a reactant and the solvent you do not count it when finding x for the concentrations, however, in this problem, it is specified that the water is *not* a solvent and the moles of water are given. I've looked in multiple sources and none have said if there is an exception with water like this.

Also, in the problem, it only refers to the water as "water", so it doesn't state that the water is pure/a pure liquid.

Thanks!

Comment: In this sort of a reaction the water counts. // For reactions like $K_a$ and $K_{sp}$ you don't count water because it is assumed that the concentration of water is constant. To be more precise you'd actually use activities of the reactants which does indirectly consider the concentration of water.